# Ecore/EMF visualization

Tags: emf, xmi, ecore, visualize

I need to visualize an instance of an ecore meta-model. 
I have an existing ecore class diagramm which represents my meta-model. After creating dynamic instances of parts of the model i get an XMI file. I want to visualize that file the same way the ecore class diagramm can be visualized in the eclipse editor.
Hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

For visualizing your model you have to create a graphical DSL based on the metamodel. One of the ways is to use Sirius.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/ allows you to create your own graphical syntax for your ecore metamodel.